# Migrating ExitAllFrames using DispatcherQueue

Tags: .net-core

I have the following code in a legacy project from .Net framework:

```cs
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
```

However, I get the following warning after migrating to .Net Core 6:

> UA306_A2  UWP CoreDispatcher : Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher is no longer supported. Use DispatcherQueue instead. Read: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/threading

My question is how can I access all frames to perform exit/dispose on them using DispatcherQueue. On the other word, how can I have similar code in the following `async` method.

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;

// ...

DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();


await dispatcherQueue.EnqueueAsync(async () =>
{
    
});
```